# Issue getting element to float within a container with multiple floating elements

Tags: css, css-float, sass

I'm having an issue getting the name div and time-ago div to float properly.  For ex, the time-ago div doesn't seem to want to float to the far right.  Here's my current HTML / CSS markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/stickboyski/qCWsk/101/

Any idea what's going on?

BTW, I am using SASS for the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent div of the time-ago div, `.metadata clearfix` has a display of inline-block. That causes its width to only be the size of its contents. You can either change its display property to `block` as demonstrated in this fork http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/KJUrL/

```
.metadata {
    display: block; /* to make width 100% of container */ 
    .name {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
    }

    .time-ago {
        float: right;
    }
}
```